# How to prevent inheritance for some methods?

Tags: c#, oop, class, inheritance

How can I prevent inheritance of some methods or properties in derived classes?!

```
public class BaseClass : Collection   
{  
    //Some operations...  
    //Should not let derived classes inherit 'Add' method.  
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass      
{        
    public void DoSomething(int Item)      
    {      
        this.Add(Item); // Error: No such method should exist...      
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The pattern you want is composition ("Has-a"), not inheritance ("Is-a").  BaseClass should contain a collection, not inherit from collection.  BaseClass can then selectively choose what methods or properties to expose on its interface.  Most of those may just be passthroughs that call the equivalent methods on the internal collection.

Marking things private in the child classes won't work, because anyone with a base type variable (`Collection x = new DerivedClass()`) will still be able to access the "hidden" members through the base type.

If "Is-a" vs "Has-a" doesn't click for you, think of it in terms of parents vs friends.  You can't choose your parents and can't remove them from your DNA, but you can choose who you associate with.

Answer (score 8):

You can't, in this instance inheritance is the wrong tool for the job. Your class needs to  have the collection as a private member, then you can expose as much or as little of it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to hide a public member of a class in a derived class is generally a bad thing(*).  Trying to hide it as a means of ensuring it won't be called is even worse, and generally won't work anyhow.

There isn't any standardized idiomatic means I know of to prevent a parent class' protected member from being accessed in a sub-derived type, but declaring a new public useless member of a clearly-useless kind would be one approach.  The simplest such thing would be an empty class.  For example, if class Foo declares an empty public class called MemberwiseClone, derivatives of Foo will be unable to call MemberwiseClone--probably a good thing if MemberwiseClone would break the invariants of class Foo.

(*) The only situation where it is appropriate is when a public method of a derived class returns a more specialized type than the corresponding method in the base class (e.g. a CarFactory.Produce() method may return a Car, while the FordExplorerFactory.Produce() method may return a FordExplorer (which derives from car).  Someone who calls Produce() on what they think is a CarFactory (but happens to be a FordExplorerFactory) will get a Car (which happens to be a FordExplorer), but someone who calls Produce() on what is known at compile time to be a FordExplorerFactory will get a result that's known at compile time to be a FordExplorer.