# c# preventing inheritance of a method

Tags: c#, inheritance, encapsulation

For a poker parser (my first project for learning c#), I have a parent class `clCardsHeld` and two child classes `clHiHand` and `clLoHand`. `clCardsHeld` also contains properties and private fields, of each of the two child types. And so what I end up with, with this inheritance, is, eg:

```
public class clCardsHeld
{public clHiHand HiHand { Get {} Set {} }
} 
public class clHiHand : clCardsHeld{}

clCardsHeld Hand3 = new clCardsHeld(); 
clHiHand hi = new clHiHand(); 
hi = Hand3.HiHand.HiHand.HiHand; 
hi = Hand3.HiHand.LoHand.HiHand;
```

(as prompted by intellisense). (`HiHand` shouldn't have another `HiHand` as a property of itself, nor a low hand. But `CardsHeld` has a `HiHand` and  `LoHand` as properties in, eg, games where you get 7 cards and you can use 5 to make to best possible hand and 5 for the worst possible, both played at the same time, for half the pot each.)

I made the base class fields private, instead of protected, so the inherited property remains `null`, if I've discerned that correctly. But really I'd like the property not to be inherited. Trying to research this, I see that a property can only be sealed when it overwrites a base property. And "hiding" the method generally refers to having different code in the child... .

One other thing, while I'm throwing out my novice questions:

```
    public class clCardsHeld { private List<clCards> _liCards; }
public class clHiHand : clCardsHeld
```

I can find `clCardsHeld._liCards` in the locals window, but I can't find `clCardsHeld.clHiCards._liCards` in the locals window (but I can get at it by assigning it to a variable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See this duplicate question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772321/how-to-prevent-inheritance-for-some-methods

Comment: please provide some sample source code.

Comment: I tried at least twice to read this, and I just can't. I have no idea what you're asking. Can you please format your question a little better? More whitespace (think paragraphs) and code formatting would help a *lot*. All you have to do is intent your code lines with 4 spaces, and they automatically show up with syntax highlighting and other goodies.

Comment: I agree with the answer in the duplicate.  Use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I saw that one, but it did not sink in that it was relevant to me. Trying to inherit Collection seemed to be coming from a different sort of confusion than my sort. I've got a lot of code to parse string input into card objects and lists, that I want common to parent and child. And I think I'd like to be able to instantiate a specifically 5-card HiHand or LoHand at times. But let me think on your advice some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the link referenced by Adeel, the inheritance in this situation is unnecessary.  Your high hand and low hands should just be new instances of clCardsHeld:

```
public class clCardsHeld
{
    private List<clCards> _liCards;

    public clCardsHeld GetLoHand()
    {
        //Logic here for returning the low hand, using _liCards
    }

    public clCardsHeld GetHiHand()
    {
        //Logic here for returning the high hand, using _liCards
    }
}
```

The GetLoHand() and GetHiHand() functions will simply return a different set of held cards.

Comment: Thanks. That's simple and very sensible.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of misconceptions in your post..

- If you want a property not to be inherited, you are violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).
- Fields are not null in a subclass just because they are private to the base class. They can still be assigned by the logic in the base class.
- It sounds to me like you are using inheritance when you don't need to.. Use inheritance when a concept (subclass) is a special case of another concept (base class). And favor composition over inheritance.

I think you should split what is common to *all* the objects into a separate base class:

```
class HandBase { /* common to both HiHand an LoHand */}
class LoHand : HandBase {}
class HiHand : HandBase {}
```

From what I can tell from your explanation, cCardsHeld does not have to have the same base type:

```
class CardsHeld
{
    public LoHand LoHand { get; private set;}
    public HiHand HiHand { get; private set;}
}
```

But if it does, then you could do this:

```
class CardsHeld : HandBase
{
    public LoHand LoHand { get; private set;}
    public HiHand HiHand { get; private set;}
}
```

If there is a property that you don't want subclasses to have, then don't put it in the base class.

Comment: Oh let me clarify one question, about the null. The problem I thought I had was trying to keep a property in the base class out of the derived class. I didn't manage that (and understand now it was the wrong idea), but what I did do was to change the access to the field behind the "problem" property to private. That seemed to have the effect that the undesired inherited instances of the property (".HiCards.HiCards") all came back as null. That's what I meant.

Comment: Changing the access modifier does not affect the value of the field. But you might have had to comment out or remove some code that assigns a value to it in order make it compile after changing the modifier. That might be the reason that would now be null.